# How to run linear regression for a specific cluster

Tags: python

I used a csv file which can be found here https://www.kaggle.com/vjchoudhary7/customer-segmentation-tutorial-in-python, and run kmeans with 4 clusters. I made a dict list to see which observations are in which clusters, the result was an array(array 0,1,2,3) . Now i want to run linear regression (and subsequently polynomial and exponential) for the observations that are in array 0. How do i do that exactly?

code:

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd




ore')
plt.show()
```

Comment: df0 = df[df.index.isin(mydict[0].tolist())] Y = df0['Spending Score (1-100)']  X = df0[['Age', 'Annual Income (k$)']]

Comment: Hi thank you it has worked! Although now i have another problem, my plot is still a mess and i don't know why. I will propably make another post this.